# Android music player keeps switching on party shuffle when brought to front

Tags: music-player

Since last week, every time I bring the standard Android music player to the front, it switches to party shuffle mode and skips away from the current tune, continuing to change tune every few 10s of seconds until I switch to normal shuffle or no shuffle.

It also drops the play history, so I cannot easily get back to the piece of music it interrupted this way.

Afterwards, if I do something else, for instance use the browser, when I switch back to the player, it switches party shuffle on again and starts skipping around as before.

I have tried clearing settings for the music player and restarting it after forcing it to stop, but it has no effect. I have heard that various bluetooth and network enabled stereo devices can do this sort of thing, but both are switched off. If I take it to a different place and additionally turn off the radio transmitter under `*#*#INFO#*#*`, it still does it, so I am inclined to believe it is not another device interfering.

As far as I am aware, it is a sudden change and I haven't updated the OS for a while or installed any apps - I have only a couple (Android version is 2.3.6 on a Nexus One).

If anybody has an idea about how to stop this sudden forcing of party shuffle upon me, I would be greatful.

Comment: One workaround is to go to the home screen, pan right, where there is a music player "applet" (mini control panel or whatever it is called). Clicking that brings the player to the front without turning on party shuffle. This does not solve the main problem that using the list of running apps brought up by holding down the home button to bring the music player to the front switches on party shuffle, though.

Comment: I thought this sort of thing was limited to Windows, but a reboot helped. It now always goes to the "Songs" tab rather than "Now Playing" after being brought to front, but at least the party shuffle stays off.